# consuming a WCF service using simple HttpClient class

Tags: wcf, httpclient

Consider the example Microsoft has on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-create-a-wcf-client

How can one consume the server using a simple HttpClient object?

There are instances where adding a Web Reference to your project is not possible. Then, using an HttpClient object might be the only way ... or adding a Server DLL reference to the Client side could also be an option.

This should be a simple example of how to call the simple double = Add(double, double) function described under:

```
namespace GettingStartedLib
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
        [OperationContract]
        double Add(double n1, double n2);
    }
}
```

Server side looks as below:

```
namespace GettingStartedLib
{
    public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 + n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Add({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            // Code added to write output to the console window.
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "consume the server using a simple HttpClient object" but why? It destroys the whole purpose of WCF! WCF is all about creating proxy classes and executing remote functions as if they were local ones. Its very easy and useful. And now you just want to neglect all of that and use some crazy stuff... Why? Just create an API project if you want to consume it with HttpClient.

Answer (score 3):

You could use http client to send a http request refer to the request content captured by Fiddle.

```
POST http://10.157.18.36:12000/Service1.svc HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IService1/Add" Host: 10.157.18.36:12000 Content-Length: 161 Expect: 100-continue Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><n1>34.23</n1><n2>80.54</n2></Add></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

WCF Service based on the web service specification.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service
They use soap message to communicate with each other via http/https protocol.
In that cases, we could use the httpclient to imitate the request.
Beside, wcf also could publish the service via http-mode, just like Asp.net web api, restful style structure.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-and-aspnet-web-api
I have made a demo, wish it is useful to you.
**IService1**

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Double Add(double n1, double n2);

}
```

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {
            return n1 + n2;
        }
}
```

**Configuration.**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="rest"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="rest">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="mex"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Client.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var  result=client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:9001/Service1.svc/add?n1=1.2&n2=3.2");
            Console.WriteLine(result.Result);

        }
```

**Result.**
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.