# Calling WCF Method through .net client requires too long time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, performance, web-services, wcf

I have a problem with my WCF Web Service, the service class and the contract class both include 650+ methods, when I create a Service client in another .net project (tested this on both desktop and website projects) using "Add Service Reference" and attempt to call one of the service client methods, response time takes too long duration that exceeds 3 minutes, which isn't acceptable.

I tried lessening the methods in the service class and contract to 5 and response time was lessened as well to less than 1 second, but lessening the methods number isn't a solution as i need the 650+ methods in my service.

The service is built with visual studio 2017 using VB.NET and hosted in both IIS and self hosted in console application.

I've been looking for a solution to this issue since two days and no answer, please help...

P.S: When calling the service methods from android application using Retrofit the response time is also fast, less than a second.

Below is a snippet regarding my web.config file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4kAx.png)

Comment: Also it's worth noticing that the delay is between the time the web service method is called from the client and the time in which the method is really hit, and not from the server side response time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Restful-style service created by WCF that typically does not use proxy classes. 
We usually use class libraries such as httpClient,webclient to construct Http requests to invoke services directly.
[consuming a WCF service using simple HttpClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53961297/consuming-a-wcf-service-using-simple-httpclient-class/53985442#53985442)
Here are some helpful links about this issue.
[The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request. wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519573/the-remote-server-returned-an-unexpected-response-400-bad-request-wcf/55527487#55527487)
[WCF: There was no endpoint listening at, that could accept the message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018130/wcf-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-that-could-accept-the-message/54068160#54068160)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that solved the problem, I used HTTPClient methodology and it retrieves the results as it should